# Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'. error

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, input, arraylist

I wanted to put the inputs values in a created P element, but it says this error. Also I wanted to delete the inputs after it replaces as well, just js please

```js
for(let i = 0; i<=12; i++){
    let pinnedinputs = document.createElement("p");

    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value = pinnedinputs .textContent;

    document.getElementsByTagName("input[i].parentNode.replaceChild(pinnedinputs,document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value)
            }
```

I tried to make a list that included all the inputs but it didn't work

Comment: are there 13 results in `document.getElementsByTagName("input")`? Also, `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value` is not a Node

Comment: You have a typo, please may you fix that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: yes there are 13 results for the inputs, actually I don't know where the typo is and I'm sorry if there's a lot of mistakes just I'm a beginner. also I didn't thought that a response would be this fast

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly, you're trying to assign the input values **to** the `<p>` element, but by doing it like that you're doing the exact opposite. You should do it like this:

```
pinnedInput.textContent = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value;
```

So your input value is assigned to the pinnedInput. Also, as Jaromanda said, `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value` is **not** a [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) since you're just pointing to the **value** of the node. The node is the input, like this: `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i]`. So, considering all of this, your code should be:

```
for(let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++){
    let pinnedInput = document.createElement("p");
    pinnedInput.textContent = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value;

    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].parentNode.replaceChild(pinnedInput, document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i]);
}
```

Comment: thank you all I didn't know what does Node actually mean

Comment: Now you know it! Wish you the best